# Chrome adding margin to the right making row wrap

Tags: css, google-chrome

All columns within the rows in chrome adding about a 15px to div.fullsize-rotator within div.inner. I have the margin for .fullsize-rotator set to margin: 0 auto. I have tried everything I can come up with. http://www.aprilsmallwood-webdesign-ui.com/. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your site and it looks like you have some extra padding in your rows.  I changed .main-grid .pad { padding: 60px 30px; ) to { padding: 60px 0px !important; } and, at least in the Chrome code inspection, it moved your third element in the row up.  It looks like that could be your problem.  It had the same effect for the Client section.  Hope this helps.

Update:  On second thought, this makes the grid too close together so the description words run in to each other.  You could do this instead:

```
.main-grid .pad {
    padding: 60px 20px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

This way you can make a little space between the elements and still have 3 per row.  You might have to play around a little with the exact left/right padding but it looks pretty close using 20px.

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect solution.